# Use a value in two Columns to return a Particular Value in a New Column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet where in Two of the columns I have Multiple Values.

Example:

```
ColA    ColB   Exp Result  
ECOM     1         2 
ECOM     1         2
ECOM     2         2
NON      1        N/A
NON      1        N/A
NON      1        N/A
LAN      1         2
LAN      2         2
LAN      1         2
```

In this example, ColB Shows values of 1 and 2. I would like to show that once ColB has a Value of 2 anything with ECOM and LAN will then Show 2 as a Result in the Exp Result Row for anything that Matches the name in ColA. Since NON only has a 1 throughout ColB, then it can show as a N/A in The Result Column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A2:A10,A2,B2:B10,2)>0,2,"N/A")
```

Should do the job

Answer (score 0):

> ...once ColB has a Value of 2

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(SUM(B:B)>COUNTA(B:B), 
 IF(LEN(A:A), IF((A:A="ECOM")+(A:A="LAN"), 2, "N/A"), ), ))
```

[image: 0]